# Keep hover effect when link is active

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

**What I would like to happen**

- My links have a hover effect. How can I make it so that effect stays on when the link is clicked / activated?
- Then, when you click a new link, I want the previous hover effect to disappear until clicked again.

I hope someone is able to help with the problem, so i can get my site up and running :)

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="menu">


            <nav id="navigation" class="site-navigation" role="navigation">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Overvågning</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li class="menu-item sub-menu"><a href="proddigi.aspx">Digital</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item sub-menu"><a href="prod-analog.aspx">Analog</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Alarm</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>

                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>



        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
}
.site-navigation {
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue LT Pro',Verdana;
    font-size: 13px;
}

    .site-navigation ul {
        background: #3498DB;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    .content-place
    {
       padding-top:400px;
    }

    .site-navigation li {
        color: #fff;
        background: #112d3b;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
        padding: 25px 18px;
        position: relative;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
        /* texten i menuen*/
        .site-navigation li a {
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            height: 33px;
            position: relative;
            display:table-cell;
            vertical-align:middle;
        }
        /* hover menuen - Det der sker når man holder musen over menuen */
        .site-navigation li:hover {
            @include transition(background, 0.2s);
            background: #1e495f; /* farve på hover*/
            cursor: pointer;
            border-bottom: 3px solid red;
        }

    .site-navigation ul li ul {
        background: #112d3b;
        visibility: hidden;
        float: left;
        width: 50px;
        position: absolute;
        transition: visibility 0.1s ease-in;
        margin-top: 25px;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 999;
    }

        .site-navigation ul li:hover > ul,
        .site-navigation ul li ul:hover {
            visibility: visible;
            z-index: 999;
        }
        /* Drop down Menuen */
        .site-navigation ul li ul li {
            clear: both;
            padding: 5px 0 5px 18px;
            width: 111px;
            height:auto;
            z-index: 999;



        }

            .site-navigation ul li ul li:hover {
                background: #1e495f;
                z-index: 999;
            }
```

Comment: Clicking the elements seems to be navigating to another page... So you want the item to be active in that page..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with jQuery like this:

```
$('.site-navigation li a').click(function() {
    $('.site-navigation li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Then just define the `.active` class the same as the hover class.

Comment: First of all, thanks alot for the help, but i don't quiet get it :) 

- What do i exactly have to do, in order to make it work.

Since i have tried alot of difference things, and it doesnt seem to work at all :) Hope you can help further.

Comment: Make sure you have the jQuery library installed. You can include it by adding this to your document just before the closing <body> tag <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: And also add:

.site-navigation li.active {
            @include transition(background, 0.2s);
            background: #1e495f; /* farve på hover*/
            cursor: pointer;
            border-bottom: 3px solid red;
        }

Comment: It still doesnt work, what i have done is the following:

I have added .site-navigation li.active { @include transition(background, 0.2s); background: #1e495f; /* farve på hover*/ cursor: pointer; border-bottom: 3px solid red; } to the css

Comment: <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#profile_list a').click(function () {
                $('#profile_list a').removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

Comment: This will only work if the links remain on the page when you click on them. If you reload the entire page, it will not work since the CSS classes will be reloaded as well. Here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WgdXU/68/).

Answer (score 0):

I just had to change the color of the classs .current then it worked smoothly